# How do I run k-means clustering in a loop for 20 data sets ? Below is the code I used

Tags: r, loops, k-means

I am trying to run k-means clustering in a loop ,but not able to do so by using below code ....could you help me ?

```
rd_1<-mydata
ID <- as.character(unique(rd_1$hotel))
length(ID)

final_data <- data.frame()
#For Loop
for (i in 1: length(ID)) { 
    test_subset <- rd_1[rd_1$hotel==ID[i],]
    #K-means clustering
    set.seed(65890)
    results<-kmeans(test_subset[,c(3:4)],centers = 3,nstart = 25)
    rd_1<-data.frame(rd_1,results$cluster) 
    final_data <-rbind(final_data,test_subset)
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that you are adding the model results back into `rd_1` instead of `test_subset`.  Try the following revision:

```
for (i in 1: length(ID)) { 
    test_subset <- rd_1[rd_1$hotel==ID[i],]
    #K-means clustering
    set.seed(65890)
    results<-kmeans(test_subset[,c(3:4)],centers = 3,nstart = 25)
    test_subset<-data.frame(test_subset,results$cluster) 
    final_data <-rbind(final_data,test_subset)
}
```